# C# - Why doesn't constructor write the initialized value?

Tags: c#, .net

Why does't this code output the value of 50?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myClass = new TestConstructor() { MyInt = 50 };
    }
}

class TestConstructor
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }

    public TestConstructor()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.MyInt);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: In general it is bad idea to use properties and especially virtual methods from within the constructor. I think this is a result of Microsoft trying simplify properties by allowing invisible field variables backing the properties and forcing access through those properties only.

Comment: @ja72: Why would you not use properties, when they're non-virtual? I agree with the perils of calling virtual methods from constructors, but properties should be fine. In particular, *setting* properties from constructors is entirely normal.

Comment: @Jon - I see your point, but it still makes me uneasy to use properties in constructors, when the fields are available instead. Maybe it is required for base class properties where fields are private (but then again the `: base(...)` syntax should be preferred). Maybe I am not pragmatic enough ... oh well.

Comment: @ja72: If the actual fields are available, I'd usually go for them - but I don't have any problem with using automatically implemented properties here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code:

```
 var myClass = new TestConstructor() { MyInt = 50 };
```

is effectively transformed into:

```
var tmp = new TestConstructor();
tmp.MyInt = 50;
var myClass = tmp;
```

How would you expect the property to be set *before* the constructor was executed?

(The use of a temporary variable here isn't important in this case, but it can be in other cases:

```
var myClass = new TestConstructor { MyInt = 50 };
myClass = new TestConstructor { MyInt = myClass.MyInt + 2 };
```

In the second line, it's important that `myClass.MyInt` still refers to the *first* object, not the newly-created one.)

Answer (score 10):

That piece of code first constructs the class, and *then* assigns 50 to the `MyInt` property, *after* the `Console.WriteLine` has been executed.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of the [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) essentially translates to this:

```
var temp = new TestConstructor();
temp.MyInt = 50;
var myClass = temp;
```

The property is being set *after* the constructor is done. If you want to ensure the property is set in the constructor you'll need to provide a constructor that accepts a parameter:

```
public TestConstructor(int myInt)
{
    MyInt = myInt;
    Console.WriteLine(MyInt);
}
```

Using it in the following manner would display the provided integer to the console window:

```
var myClass = new TestConstructor(50);
```

Comment: It's more accurate to say that it is translated into the creation of a temporary, then the constructor call, then the assignment to the property, and then the assignment of the temporary to the variable. See Jon's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is translated as

```
 var myClass = new TestConstructor(); //Here occures Console.Write(). myInt is 0 now
 myClass.MyInt = 50;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the syntax you use first creates the object and calls the constructor and then sets your value.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling new TestConstructor() and only in a second time you sat the property!

Answer (score 1):

When using an object initializer like you are using, the default constructor is called first and THEN the various properties and fields you are setting are set.

This means that you're probably seeing the value of `default(int)` in the console here, since you don't set the value in the constructor itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a value-setting constructor" here? I suspect you mean "an object initializer" but it's worth being clear.